# What are the async benefits on the backend?

Tags: asynchronous

I understand the benefits of async on the frontend (some kind of UI). With async the UI does not block and the user can "click" on other things while waiting for another operation to execute.

But what is the benefit of async programming on the backend?

Comment: Well, running things in parallel, not blocking cpu while io operations, and so on

Comment: Please comment why the down vote?

Comment: To take advantages of your full computing resources.

Comment: @joe great comment. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at docs about multi-threading. Just as Florian said, async is actually using `task` to open new threads to process your codes asynchronously in parallel. For example, you have a 8-Core cpu, a single thread program only allows you to process on 1 of its core. Multi-thread can allows you to use multi-core in parallel. Of course the mechanism is not that simple in practice.  If you want to know the details, read books.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit is that there could be various slow operations on the backend, which can prevent other requests from using the cpu at the same time. These operations could be: 1. Database operations 2. File operations 3. Remote calls to other services (servers), etc. You don't want to block the cpu while these operations are in progress.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there a benefit of handling more than one request at a time. Frameworks like ASP.net or django create new (or reuse existing) threads for each requests.

If you mean async operations from the thread of particular request, that's more complicated. In most cases, it does not help at all, because of the overhead of spawning new thread. But, we have things like Schedulers in C# for example, which help a lot. When correctly used, they free up a lot of CPU time normally wasted on waiting.

For example, you send a picture to a server. Your request is handled in new thread. This thread can do everything on it's own: upack the picture and save it to disk, then update the database. 
Or, you can write to disk AND update the database at the same time. The thread that is done first is our focus here. When used without scheduler, it starts spinning a loop, checking if the other thread is done, which takes CPU time. If you use scheduler, it frees that thread. When the other task is done, it uses propably yet another precreated thred to finish handling of your request.

That scenario does make it seem like it's not worth the fuss, but it is easy to imagine more coplicated tasks, that can be done in the same time instead of sequentailly. On top of that, schedulers are rather smart and will make it so the total time needed will be lowest, and CPU usage moderate.